# Get no result from LDAP query

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to filter out employees from a specific OU via LDAP.
The problem is that the OU contains spaces.
By itself, with \20 between the respective words, this OU should be resolved and be able to be found.
Furthermore, there is no CN in the respective OU.

What I have tried so far is the following:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(ou=test\20user\20accounts,dc=lab,dc=local))
```

Unfortunately I only get an empty output.

The searchbase is missing and i dont know how to implement it in the ldap query.

With Powershell i dont have any issues to get what i want:

```
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(ObjectClass=user)"  -SearchBase "ou=test\20user\20accounts,dc=lab,dc=local" -Properties *  |`
? {$_.ObjectCategory -like "cn=Person*" }| select name,objectclass,ObjectCategory | fl
```

I appreciate any advice :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You do not supply enough information to make an accurate assessment.

What are you looking for within OU=Test,User,Accounts,DC=Lab,DC=local?
"I wanna get all the members of the OU Test User Accounts"

This should get all "Users" (sAMAccountType=805306368) in the container "OU=Test,User,Accounts,DC=Lab,DC=local" (With some tweaking to fit your server and credentials)

```
ldapsearch -D "cn=exampleuser,example.com" -w secret  -h server.example.com -b "OU=Test,User,Accounts,DC=Lab,DC=local" -s sub "(sAMAccountType=805306368)"
```

Comment: I am sorry, I wanna get all the members of the OU Test User Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

To search for users in an OU, set the search root of your query (sometimes called Base DN) to the OU. It cannot be done in the filter.

The `memberOf` attribute is used for groups, not OU's.

Comment: Can you may tell me what your suggestion is in that case to get all the users of the OU "Test User Accounts"?

Comment: (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(OU=test\20user\20accounts,DC=lab,DC=local))
For example isnt working for me. Can you may help me out?

Comment: There is no filter you can use to do this. You need to change the search root. That's what you did with your PowerShell command where you set the `-SearchBase` to the OU.

Comment: Could you may help me to do this for the ldap query?

Comment: Can you update your question and show the code you are using to make the search?

Comment: Sure, ive updated the question and have updated the code im using right now as well. Thank you so much.

Comment: If it's working in PowerShell, why do you want to change it? Are you trying to make the same search in something other than PowerShell?

Comment: We are currently integrating the MFA into our company. Unfortunately, this requires me to generate an LDAP query.

Comment: Right, but any time an LDAP query is executed, you always have to specify a search root (or search base). The only way you can limit the results to one OU is to set that search root. It is impossible to do in the LDAP filter.

Comment: Oh man, so sorry. You are completely right. I will put the necessary accounts into a group and will search for them with "memberOf" parameter. Thank you for the help =)